# How can I get a label to right align in a table "cell" (td)?

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table

I've got this html:

```
<td>
  <label class="whitefont righthoralign">Search</label>
</td>
```

...with this CSS:

```
.righthoralign {
    text-align: right;
}
```

...which does nothing - the label stays left aligned as before:

[image]

What I found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp), namely this:

```
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

...made things far worse.

How can I get the label to hug the right side of the cell/td in which it finds itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<label>` element is inline level, the width is the size of the label text by default.

Try:

```
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Or:

```
td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add text align to the td element.

```
td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

You can also remove the text align from the label as it has no effect on the element (it is inline).

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamnottony/52zbfe2e/1/